# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'COLOR_BRG2GRAY'

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Estou a fazer o resize de imagens de uma pasta e estou a encontrar o seguinte erro:  module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'COLOR_BRG2GRAY'
Código:

```
pathC = './cityscape/'
dirs = os.listdir(pathC)

#Resize para o pathC np.array

def resize():
    path = pathC
    os.path.exists(path)
    orig = cv2.imread('./cityscape/')
    for img in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+img):
            img = cv2.imread(path+img)
            img2 = np.array(cv2.resize(img,(512,512)))
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BRG2GRAY)

resize()
```

Erro:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'COLOR_BRG2GRAY'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O certo é COLOR_BGR2GRAY e não 'COLOR_BRG2GRAY'.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Os tipos de conversão podem ser vistos [aqui](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html).

Comment: Mais tarde reparei que tinha trocado as letras em quanto escrevia com a presa, obrigado.

Comment: Acontece mesmo. hehe